# How do you get $\rm{var}(\Theta -\hat\theta) = \rm{var}(\Theta)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, variance

From this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYQ3NF-bHaA&t=325) on Bayesian Least Mean Square estimation:

$$\mathbf E\left[(\Theta -\hat\theta)^2\right] = \rm{var}(\Theta -\hat\theta) + \left(\mathbf E[\Theta -\hat\theta]\right)^2 = \rm{var}(\Theta) + \left(\mathbf E[\Theta -\hat\theta]\right)^2$$

which is to say that $\rm{var}(\Theta -\hat\theta) = \rm{var}(\Theta)$.  I would like to ask how that comes about?  Thanks.

$\Theta$ is the random variable being estimated, and $\hat\theta$ is a constant estimate.

Comment: What is $\Theta$ and $\hat\theta$?

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: easy-peasy.  The variance subtracts the mean.  Adding a constant is a mean offset, thus it is removed when computing the variance.

Comment: Thank you!  Makes sense now.